# Why do I get the error 'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass' in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I'm very new to RoR, I would definitely appreciate any help!

I had this block of code in my 'index' file but I wanted to move it into my 'application' file so that it appears on the navigation of each page:

```
<ul class="blogs">
  <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <li>  
      <%= link_to blog.name, blog.url, { :target => 'main-iframe'} %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= link_to 'New Blog', new_blog_path %>
```

This works fine and displays correctly. However the links 'Edit' and 'New Blog' no longer work at all, they take me to the error page below (please note, the links worked fine when they were in the index page):

NoMethodError in Blogs#new

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

specific problem is this line:

```
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
```

The URL is still correct (/blogs/new) but that line seems to be blocking something on this page.

In my blogs_controller.rb page I have (amongst a few other things):

```
def index
  @blogs = Blog.all
end
def new
  @blog = Blog.new
end
def edit
end
```

Could anyone please assist me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post code on `new.html.erb`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because in the new action @blogs is nil. You can try

```
def new
  @blogs = Blog.all
  @blog = Blog.new
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to appear on several pages, you should create a before filter:

```
before_filter :load_blogs

def load_blogs
  @blogs = Blog.all
end

def index 
end
```

Some remarks:

- consider caching data instead of querying database each time a page is loaded
- consider using pagination, `.all` could bloat your app if there are too many blogs